# Does the convergence of the limit superior imply the sequence is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

It's true that the limit superior of any bounded sequence converges. However, I haven't seen the converse of this, so I'm trying to prove it. That is, I need to show that if the limit superior of a sequence converges, then the sequence is bounded.

Here's my proof:

Denote the sequence in question by $(a_n)$ and let $y_n=\sup\lbrace a_k: k\ge n\rbrace$. From the definition of limit superior, we have that the sequence $(y_n)$ converges or $\lim\sup a_n=\lim y_n$ exists.

(a) $(a_n)$ is bounded above can be decuded trivially by the fact that $y_1=\sup\lbrace a_k: k\ge 1\rbrace$ exists implies that $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $y_1$.

(b) Suppose to the contrary that $(a_n)$ is not bounded below, then $\forall M\lt 0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\lt M, \forall n\gt N$. This implies $y_n=\sup\lbrace a_k: k\ge n\rbrace\le M, \forall n\gt N$, so $(y_n)$ diverges to infinity which is a contradiction to the hypothesis that $\lim y_n$ exists. Therefore, $(a_n)$ has to be bounded below and thus from (a), we conclude that $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Is there anything wrong with this proof especially in part (a) where I'm basing on the fact that $y_1$ has to be exist for the sequence $(y_n)$ to be defined?

Comment: Part (a) is fine, part (b) is wrong - why $y_n \leq M$? Also, the claim itself isn't true: take sequence $(0, -1, 0, -2, 0, -3, 0, -4, \ldots)$ - it's $\limsup$ is $0$, but it's not bounded below.

Comment: My blunder! I mistook $\inf$ for $\sup$. Thanks for the example also!

Comment: While (a) is true, it misses the real point. Limits are about the tail of a sequence only, so the beginning values could be undefined and the limit would still be the same. The full reason (a) holds is that for the limit superior to exist, at least for some $n, y_n$ exists. And $y_1 = \sup \{a_k : k\ge 1\} = \max \{a_1,\dots, a_{n-1}, y_n\}$, so it must exist as well.